# How to structure git workflow for multiple features with different timelines for production?

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git. I am trying to learn it and implement it in my environment. I am working on a dashboard that has 2 features that developers are working on in my team.

**Workflow**

3 branches in the repository: Development, Testing and Production.

- Developers work on fixes for features in separate branches.
- Once fixes are implemented, they are merged into the
  testing branch for the corresponding feature and deployed to the testing environment for testing.
- After testing is complete, the branch is merged into the development branch.
- Once the feature is ready for production, the development branch is merged into production and then deployed to the Production environment.

| Type | Time0 | Time1 | Time2 | Time3 | Time4 | Time5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Status | Start of the process | Both features moved to v1 | Testing complete | FeatureA moved to v2 | FeatureA is ready for release | FeatureA v2 in production |
| Action |  |  | Merge testing to development |  | Merge testing to development | Merge development to production |
| Development Branch | FeatureA v0 FeatureB v0 | FeatureA v0 FeatureB v0 | FeatureA v1 FeatureB v1 | FeatureA v1 FeatureB v1 | FeatureA v2 FeatureB v1 | FeatureA v2 FeatureB v1 |
| Testing Branch | FeatureA v0 FeatureB v0 | FeatureA v1 FeatureB v1 | FeatureA v1 FeatureB v1 | FeatureA v2 FeatureB v1 | FeatureA v2 FeatureB v1 | FeatureA v2 FeatureB v1 |
| Production Branch | FeatureA v0 FeatureB v0 | FeatureA v0 FeatureB v0 | FeatureA v0 FeatureB v0 | FeatureA v0 FeatureB v0 | FeatureA v0 FeatureB v0 | FeatureA v2 FeatureB v1 |

The problem that I am facing with this workflow is that at `Time5`, the `production branch` has `FeatureA v2, FeatureB v1` but ideally I want it to be `FeatureA v2, FeatureB v0`. This is because only **FeatureA** is ready for production and **FeatureB** is still in testing phase.

My **desired output** at `Time5` for `production branch` would `FeatureA v2 FeatureB v0`.

What am I missing in my workflow? How do I manage my workflow deployments when developers are working on multiple features but different timelines for release to production?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How did FeatureB v1 get into the Development branch?

Comment: Also, you probably wanted to use FeatureA instead of Feature1 in the Status line.

Comment: @choroba FeatureB and FeatureA had v1 ready and pushed to the testing branch. Once tested, I merged the testing branch to the development branch so that is how both features have v1. This is where I am doing something wrong and I am seeking for help.

Comment: The gitflow as I know it doesn't have a "testing" branch (but there usually is a "release" branch). If something is not ready to be released, either work on a fix in the testing branch, or revert it and release it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There's a contradiction in your workflow

You say:

> My desired output at Time5 for production branch would FeatureA v2 FeatureB v0.

yet in Time1 you have both `FeatureA v1` and `FeatureB v1` pushed to Test.

If you want to be able to release feature changes into production independently, *you must test them independently*. Otherwise you are not testing the exact code you putting into prod.

Since the path must be:  `dev --> test --> prod`, and since from your chart it looks like you have only one test team, then only one feature branch should be merged into Test at a time; the others will have to wait.

### Nix the `Development` branch. Having both doesn't buy you anything

I'm not sure what role the `Development Branch` in your workflow plays. The only point of having a `Development` branch is so that you can integrate separate feature branches that are going to be released together. But you want features to be released to prod totally independently, so it doesn't make sense for you.

If you want to keep each feature's development, test and release to prod independent, they have to stay separate until tested and released to prod! In your workflow in Time1 you merged two features into Test... So (1) you are not testing them separately making it unsafe to push to prod separately and (2) if you merge them you can't push only one to prod anyway!

Merging your features branch changes into each other introduces a lot of complexity, as explained in [Topic branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows#_topic_branches). So it is better to keep them separate until production. When a feature does goes into production, or into pre-production, passes testing and is scheduled to go into production, only then do you merge that feature into all the other feature branches (simplest approach is to rebase all feature branches onto the tagged commit in Pre-production).

If you need to occasionally make sure the features are compatible, you could use a [Throw-away integration](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows#_throw_away_integration) branch.

See [5 Git workflows and branching strategy you can use to improve your development process](https://zepel.io/blog/5-git-workflows-to-improve-development/). Essentially I'm telling you to use the `Git Feature Branch Workflow` and not `Git Feature Workflow with Develop Branch`, except you will have a `Test` or `Preproduction` branch that all changes to `Production` will go through.

### Just have a `Pre-production` branch for testing

My suggestion assumes you have only one test team. Even if you have multiple, because of your desire to push features to prod independently, you really have to test things in the order they are pushed to prod. For example if A is to be release before B, A must be tested in isolation, then A+B must be tested. If you reverse the release order, you have to redo all the testing (first B, then B+A).

The simplest solution is to have one `Pre-production` or `Test` branch (either name works).

- **`Feature X`** branches, e.g. `FeatureA` and `FeatureB`

  These branches should always include the latest production (via merge or rebase).
- **`Pre-production`** branch

  Features that considered done and candidates for production are merged into `Pre-production` and tested before being pushed to `Production`. For example:

  Say `FeatureB v1` is ready first. It is merged into `Pre-production` and the branch is locked from further changes while testing is in progress. If tests pass, and a tag is created to mark that commit as having passed tests and OK to be merged to production.

  Now `FeatureA v1` or `FeatureB v2` can be merged into `Pre-production` and undergo testing without having to wait for `FeatureB v1` to be merged into production *because the tag created marking the tested code* allows you to push only the tested code into production. `FeatureB v1` can be pushed to production on its own, or you can wait until some more features pass testing to do a larger rollout of features.
- **`Production`** branch

### Other Workflow models

If you need something more fancy, there are plenty of workflow designs you can find on the web.

- Gitflow: [A successful Git branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successfulgit-branching-model/)
- [Git Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow)

See also [gitworkflows](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows) and [4 branching workflows for Git](https://medium.com/@patrickporto/4-branching-workflows-for-git-30d0aaee7bf).

Comment: thanks for your response. I was trying to work this out and took a couple of days to get back to you. I have 2 questions. 1) Is the locking of dev branch necessary? 2) How do you push "FeatureB v1" to production on its "own" while FeatureA v1 is also in the dev branch? I would really appreciate it if you could clarify that for me.

Comment: @Sharath I added a preface to my answer above. The reason you have to lock Pre-production is because as I explain above, you have to control what gets tested. If `FeatureB v1` is in the middle of testing, and `FeatureA v1` pushed there, you are no longer testing Bv1, but Bv1+Av1.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This makes sense now. I will try to implement this in my current work.